# sh script misbehaving in bash, not in gnome-terminal

Tags: java, bash, shell, ubuntu, gnome-terminal

I'm trying to launch script which launches java application(Android CTS) from java, but depending how I start script application misbehave.

What I trying to run: ./cts-tradefed run cts

When script is started from shell it works ok

When script is started:

```
ProcessBuilder().command(command.split(" ")).directory(ctsToolsPath).inheritIO().start()
```

Application is working but with bug (not all devices are tested)

When script is started:

```
ProcessBuilder().command(*arrayOf("gnome-terminal", "-e").plus(command)).directory(ctsToolsPath).start().waitFor()
```

Everything works ok, but I can capture output.

When script is started in shel but with redirection:

```
 ./cts-tradefed run cts > somefile
```

It also is working with a bug.
I've tested in like a million times and I can't find what is the difference between approches to launch, that would lead to application misbehaving.

**Solution:**

Problem was with running CTS as interactive console. I was able to solve with with parameter commandAndExit

```
cts-tradered run commandAndExit ...
```

Comment: Can you post the script itself? Often these problems are caused by differences in the PATH and other environment variables between the methods of invocation.

Comment: Script: https://pastebin.com/uPnj9Xnf

Comment: However even simple redirection > breaks application.

Comment: What happens if you `| tee somefile` instead of simply re-direct?

Comment: App is working with a bug. Either | or > breaks something. I think when I or > is used it is script is launched differently.

Comment: So it looks like something is testing to check if stdout is not a file/pipe and behaving differently. Line 124, from the name 'compatibilityConsole', might be doing this to see if it has a real terminal for output.

Comment: @user2186425 : Did you verify that the script is running with the same bash version in both cases? I would also check the value of PATH in both cases. If it is different, a wrong version of some tool you are using might be picked up.

Comment: Same bash version, same PATH :(

Comment: using pty is better than 'run commandAndExit'.